# Programmatically initialize number of buttons

Tags: r, gwidgets

I have a parameter `b` that depends on the program execution and I need to create `b` buttons (`gbutton`). However, I don't know how to do that.

Comment: A loop? The difficulty would be labeling, and assigning the appropriate handler. This would be parameterized by the looping variable.

Comment: @jverzani  Yes it is the difficulty I have. I tried to struggle with `assign`function but get no success. Could you elaborate sth about that ?

Comment: My point is you need to associate an index with both a label and a handler. Suppose these are functions `alabel` and `ahandler`, then you might have something like this: `sapply(1:b, function(i) gbutton(alabel(i), cont=g, handler=ahandler(i)))`.